# Addressing Ambiguous Redirect in Unix Pipe

Tags: linux, unix, pipe

I have a code that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
file1=foo.txt
file2=bar.txt
ouput=output.txt

join $file1 <(cut -f1 $file2 | sort -u) > $output

# We will further process $output
```

But it give me such error.

```
./mycode.sh: line 4: $output: ambiguous redirect
```

Is there a way to address it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cut -f1 $file2 | sort -u > sort.txt
join $file1 sort.txt > $output
```

just a bit curios, you don't get any other error message?

Comment: Or I'd expect that `cut -f1 $file2 | sort -u | join $file1 - >$output` would work.  `join` does appear to require two arguments, so (possibly depending on the unix, I suppose) that might account for the error in the version in the question.